# Surface to Dual Monitors

Tags: microsoft-surface-pro-3, dual-connections

How can i connect my Surface Pro 3 to dual Dell LCD Monitors Model: 1909Wb?

If it is possible, what cables would I need and how would they need to be set up?

Comment: The [Microsoft Surface Dock](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/d/microsoft-surface-dock/8qrh2npz0s0p?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) sold by Microsoft would allow you to accomplish your goals.   The SP3 has a single mini-DisplayPort.  What cables you would need, depend on what ports your monitor has, so look at the specifications for your monitor to determine that.  The Microsoft Surface Dock has two mini-DisplayPorts

Answer (score 0):

I have done the research for you. East of the monitors you want to connect, model [Dell UltraSharp 1909W](https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-ultrasharp-1909w-lcd-monitor-19-series/specs/), has a DVI-D port and a VGA port.

As mentioned above, the Surface 3 Display Dock has two mini-DisplayPorts. Therefore, you will need a mini-DisplayPort to VGA or mini-DisplayPort to DVI port for each computer, such as this one [on Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.ca/StarTech-com-Mini-DisplayPort-VGA-Adapter/dp/B0031SEMBQ). You would connect each monitor's VGA ports to the Surface Display Dock's mini-DisplayPorts, and then go into Display settings in the Settings App (Windows 10) or Control Panel (Windows 8) to verify your monitors are detected and configure them the way you want them; i.e. extend, duplicate, etc.

If you need any more help, please reach out to us. We are always here for you.

Comment: The Microft Surface Pro 3 only has a single mini display port.  How could I Daisy chain the Monitors?

Comment: "How could I Daisy chain the Monitors?" - **You don't.**  You won't be able to daisy chain, over mini-DisplayPort, with monitors that themselves don't support the required DisplayPort standard.  You can use the docking station, and connect each monitor to one port each, with the appropriate cable.